# Is there a standard way to refer to a range of equations?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have occasionally wanted to refer to a range of equations in my document.  So far, I've been using `Equations~\eqref{firstEquation}~--~\eqref{lastEquation}`, which produces something like "Equations (5) - (12)".  I recognize that this could make it harder to maintain the document if equations get shifted around, but I still prefer it to something like "Equations (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), and (12)".

Is there a standard or accepted way to refer to a range of equations like this?  Or should I just keep doing whatever looks best to me?

Comment: Check out the `cleveref` package. You can write: `see \cref{aneq,anothereq,andanothereq,onemoreeq}` and get "see equations (5)-(8) and (16)"

Comment: @Lev: This is impossible! (or a rather bad bug in `\cref` that outputs more references than you specify) ;-) Also: This should be an answer.

Comment: @Caramdir: feel free to write a proper answer. I don't have time now.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (15th Edition) says:

> A range of equations is referred to by giving the first and last equation
>   numbers, joined by an en dash: From equations (2)–(5) we obtain . . .

Also, *The Manual of Scientific Style* recommends to use the en-dash:

> For separating numbers in order to
>   indicate a range, use an en-dash...

To automate this process, you could use the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package, which automatically sorts and compresses a range of references; this package aldo provides the `\crefrange` command (and variants) to easily refer to a range of labels. You can customize the way the ranges are to be typeset. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{equ:one}
a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{equ:two}
c=d
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{equ:three}
e=f
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{equ:four}
g=h
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{equ:five}
i=j
\end{equation}

See~\cref{equ:three,equ:one,equ:five,equ:two}

\Crefrange{equ:two}{equ:five}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get an en-dash instead of the word "to" you need to add

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

to the preamble of the document.

EDIT: updated the example with an example of `\Crefrange`, and added the recommendations from the style manuals.

Comment: Should I write 'Equations' with upper case? Or 'equations'?

Comment: Note that there is one pitfall with the `\Crefrange{equ:two}{equ:five}` reference. If you add an additional equation between, e.g., `equ:three` and `equ:four` (like `equ:threeAndHalf`), then the `Crefrange` command will simply extend the range, while explicitly listing your equations as in `\cref{equ:three,equ:one,equ:five,equ:two}` will protect you from this problem.