# Why there is no \labelcrefrange?

Tags: listings, cleveref

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{lstnumber}{line}{lines}
\Crefname{lstnumber}{Line}{Lines}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@,numbers=left]
{A}@\label{lineref1}@
x:=1@\label{lineref2}@
{B}@\label{lineref3}@
y:=2@\label{lineref4}@
{C}@\label{lineref5}@
\end{lstlisting}
See the Hoare-triples at \namecrefs{lineref1} \ref{lineref1}--\ref{lineref3}, \ref{lineref3}--\ref{lineref5}.
%\labelcrefrange{lineref1}{lineref3}, \labelcrefrange{lineref3}{lineref5}
\end{document}
```

The output is [image: output]

With the (non-existing) `\labelcrefrange`, the input could have been a little bit more abstract: one would have to provide the format for the ranges only once per document (as opposed to spelling out the double hyphen without surrounding spaces on each use).  Does such a command exist in cleveref (or some other standard packages)?

Comment: Did you try `\crefrange`? To get the dash you'll also need to add `\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}` to your preamble. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18988/156366).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little need for `\labelcrefrange` (to exist), when what you want can be produced by simply using `\cref`. This is because compression of cross-references can be prevented by providing suitable “empty labels” via extra commas (see Section 5 of the [`cleveref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{lstnumber}{line}{lines}
\Crefname{lstnumber}{Line}{Lines}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
%\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@,numbers=left]
{A}@\label{lineref1}@
x:=1@\label{lineref2}@
{B}@\label{lineref3}@
y:=2@\label{lineref4}@
{C}@\label{lineref5}@
z:=3@\label{lineref6}@
{D}@\label{lineref7}@
\end{lstlisting}
See the Hoare-triples at \namecrefs{lineref1} \ref{lineref1}--\ref{lineref3}, \ref{lineref3}--\ref{lineref5}.
%\labelcrefrange{lineref1}{lineref3}, \labelcrefrange{lineref3}{lineref5}

\noindent
See the Hoare-triples at
\cref{lineref1,lineref2,lineref3,,lineref3,lineref4,lineref5,,lineref5,lineref6,lineref7}.
\end{document}
```

[image: references]

To get rid of the “and”, uncomment the line `\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, }`.

Comment: @user49915 Line breaks are allowed in two places: 1) Between the first comma and the following `3`; 2) Between the `5` and the `and`. For Oxford comma, you should use `\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define it using internal macros of `cleveref`

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\labelcrefrange}[2]{\@crefrangenostar{labelcref}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```